# iterating over <class 'django.http.request.QueryDict'>?

Tags: python, django

i am sending a post request via ajax to the django's backend. When i print the respnse using print(type(request.POST)) the output is () . now i want to type cast it in dictionary and then iterate through it.

```
def checkoutnow(request):
    dict_items = {}
    p = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':

        print(type(request.POST))
        m = request.POST
        print(dict(m))
        m = dict(m)
        print(m['object[0][name]'])
        print(len(m))
        m.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
        print(len(m))
        for i in range(int(len(m)/5)):
            dict_items = {i : {'name':f"object[{i}][name]", 'qty': f"object[{i}][qty]"}}
        p = len(m)/5
        print(dict_items)
        return render(request, "mart/checkout.html")
```

when i typecasted it in dict()... the output is :

```
{'object[0][name]': ['new5'], 'object[0][id]': ['5'], 'object[0][price]': ['888'], 'object[0][qty]': ['7'], 'object[0][category]': ['new arrival'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['lkPPM58fYxegavTCAz75mN5EiFvynjIr27khr78AYdQRIb49nhT4YFjcTuuVwlLb']}
```

therefore i pop the last item and then iterate it using f string but the problem is with the output: 
     {0: {'name': 'object[0][name]', 'qty': 'object[0][qty]'}}

Looks like the keys that i am iterating via f strings are not putting the values...how can i iterate through it?

Comment: `request.POST` is a `QueryDict` which is a subclass of `dict` so it's already a dictionary. You don't need to type cast it at all, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also you need to go back to the python docs and learn how f-strings work: string interpolation is done by putting the variable between curly braces: `f"{object[i][name]}"`. But why would you do that if you don't put anything else in the string? `object[i][name]` on its own is already the `name` string.

Comment: i want to iterate query dict using for loop, can you share a code snippet for it?

Comment: Like any [python dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), you can do `for key, value in my_dict.items()` which returns a list of key, value pairs. Or if you only want to iterate over the keys: `for key in my_dict` or only the values `for value in my_dict.values()`.

Comment: cuz it says "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" when i iterate it with for like this "for k,v in m:". that is why i typcasted it. ....

Comment: see my comment above, that explains your error.

Comment: Note that if your POST is submitting multiple values for the same key, `for key, value in request.POST.lists()` will return these lists. `request.POST.items()` will only return the last item for each key.